# TemplateDoesNotExist at /prueba/

Tags: django, django-urls

Me devuelve error de template, no consigo que se vea la página html (runserver va bien, pero al ejecutar http://127.0.0.1:8000/prueba/ es cuando da error):

**TemplateDoesNotExist at /prueba/**
**estacion/estaciones.html**

Archivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

**View.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class PruebaView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'estacion/estaciones.html'
```

**Url.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('prueba/', views.PruebaView.as_view()),    
]
```

Settings:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Configuraste bien los templates? Según veo la carpeta `templates` esta en el proyecto, debes indicarle a Django que busque los templates también en esa carpeta, en la constante `TEMPLATES`, específicamente en la key `DIRS`, de tu archivo `settings.py`.

Comment: En DIRS parece que se menciona el templates, he añadido 2 recortes del archivo setting por si alguien ve el error.

Comment: Según veo hiciste modificaciones al `BASE_DIR`, y la forma en que gestiona las rutas por defecto, Django, lo ideal seria que no hagas dichas modificaciones. No conozco la librería `unipath` y creo que el problema es que no estas gestionando muy bien las rutas con dicha librería.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que tenes mal configurada la variables DIRS en los settings. Proba con la siguiente configuración:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Con eso Django deberia ser capaz de buscar en tu carpeta templates.
Saludos